# Pig: How to give input to pig script from file

Tags: python, apache-pig

I have a file 'input'. There are around 600 email addresses in input. I need to take this 600 email addresses and see if there is a match for any of these in a dataset. How to load this 600 email addresses as input to the pig script. Can I do this using python?

Comment: I have thought about doing a join, but is there a way to keep the list 0f 600 email addresses in memory ( as its size is really small) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [replicated joins](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#replicated-joins)?